Existence and uniqueness of heteroclinic solution of Allen–Cahn on $\mathbb R$ with driving-damping term
The Allen–Cahn equations on $\mathbb R$ are $u'' = u^3 - u$. It is well-known that all the solutions of this equation which satisfy the asymptotic boundary conditions $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u\left(x\right) = \pm 1$ are the "heteroclinic solutions" $\tanh\left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sqrt 2}\right)$, obtained by translating the fundamental odd solution with $x_0 = 0$.
I am interested in an equation of the form
$$ u'' = - f(x) \cdot u' + u^3 - u \tag{$*$}\label{483650_star} $$
where $f(x)$ is an odd sigmoid function similar to $ \tanh\left(x\right)$, satisfying $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f\left(x\right) = \pm A$ for some $A>0$. I would like to understand whether this equation has a unique heteroclinic solution with asymptotic boundary conditions $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u\left(x\right) = \pm 1$.
Here's a hand-wavy argument that makes me think this could be true.
By elementary considerations, it is easy to prove that any solution $u$ of \eqref{483650_star} for which $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u\left(x\right) = \pm 1$ satisfies $\left| u \right| < 1$ and is strictly increasing. Therefore, by Picard–Lindelof, a solution is uniquely determined by $u\left(0\right)$ and $u'\left(0\right)$. Now, since $\left| u \right| < 1$, $u\left(0\right)$ is in the "valley" of the potential $-\left(1-u^2\right)^2$ between between $-1$ and $1$. If the initial momentum $u'\left(0\right)$ is too small, $u$ will oscillate around $0$ and, since the "damping coefficient" $f(x)$ is non-negative on $x \geq 0$, $u$ will lose energy and converge asymptotically to $0$. On the other hand, if $u'\left(0\right)$ is too big, $u$ will be able to reach the top of the hill $u = 1$ in finite time with a positive momentum, and then it will fall downhill along the potential $-\left(1-u^2\right)^2$ for $u>1$ and diverge in finite time. It feels like, calling $v_0$ the sup of the initial momenta $v$ for which the solution of the IVP $u\left(0\right) = 0, u'\left(0\right) = v$ converges to $0$ asymptotically, the solution IVP $u\left(0\right) = 0, u'\left(0\right) = v_0$ should converge asymptotically to $1$. Time-reversing the solution, we should get our desired heteroclinic solution.
Concerning uniqueness, the idea is that if there is another solution $u$, then it must be $u\left(0\right) = u_0 \not = 0$. Arguing as above, there should be a unique $v_0 = v_0\left( u_0 \right)$ for which the IVP $u\left(0\right) = u_0 , u'\left(0\right) = v_0$ converges asymptotically to $1$. But now, if we time reverse, the solution will necessarily blow up in finite time, due to the fact that $f\left(x \right)$ is not translation invariant.
Are there general theorems/techniques that allow me to turn this hand-wavy argument (if correct at all) into a proof?
